# Real Weights Knapsack in polynomialtime

Tags: runtime, time-complexity, knapsack-problem, np

> In the lecture, we have considered the Knapsack problem: There are n items with positive weights
>   w1, . . . , wn and values v1, . . . , vn and a knapsack (a bag) of capacity W. A feasible solution to the
>   problem is a subset of the items such that their total weight does not exceed W. The objective is to
>   find a feasible solution of maximum possible total value.
>   For the case where all weights are positive integers, we have discussed a dynamic programming solution
>   that solves the knapsack problem in time O(nW).
>
> ---
>
> a)Assume that instead of the weights, the values of all items are positive integers. The weights of
>   the items can be arbitrary positive real numbers. Describe a dynamic programming algorithm that
>   solves the knapsack problem if all values are positive integers.

Idea - Round the values but this would just be a approximation right? This does only work if we have limited limited decimal space...

is there an other approach?

Im even more confused of the next questions:

> b) What is the running time of your algorithm? Justify your answer.
>
> ---
>
> c) Knapsack is one of Karp’s NP-complete problems. Both dynamic programming solutions lead to
>   polynomial time algorithms. Why is this not a contradiction to the NP-completeness of Knapsack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part A: Since the values of all items are positive integers, and therefore the items cannot be broken meaning the items have to be taken as a whole or left behind, this is an example of the 0/1 Knapsack problem. This problem lacks the Greedy Choice Property and so cannot be solved by a Greedy approach. Dynamic Programming is necessary.

Say for example we have item 1 (total value: $60, weight: 10lbs, value/weight: $6/lb), item 2 (total value: $100, weight: 20lbs, value/weight: $5/lb), and item 3: (total value: $120, weight: 30lbs, value/weight: $4/lb).

With a greedy approach you take the most valuable item first. item 1+item 2=$160. This is not the optimal solution since if we include item 1, other items might be forced out and empty space could remain. Must look at the solution with item 1 vs. solution without item 1. This is called overlapping subproblems.

For an optimal solution, either our last item n is in the optimal solution A, or it is not.

- If it is: The rest of the objects in the optimal solution can be found by finding optimal solution given N-{n} items and max capacity of C-s{sub n}.
- If it is not: The rest of the objects in the optimal solution can be found by finding optimal solution given N-{n} items and max capacity of C.

To find max value(N,C):
 - if s{sub n} <= C: max(value(N-{n},C),v{sub n} + value(N-{n},C-s{sub n}))
 - if s{sub n} > C: value(N-{n},C)

As this is a lot of subproblems to try, create a table with #columns = size of backpack + 1 (i.e. 0...C, with C being size of backpack), and #rows = inputs in any order. Fill out the table with the rules listed above starting at C=0 and going across the table for each item. Choose the combination that provides the highest capacity and highest total worth.

Part B: The running time of the algorithm is O((Cn)^2). The table is Capacity x number of items. Each element in the table compares 2 values (max of not including element n{sub k}, and including element n{sub k}).

Part C: The 0/1 Knapsack is NP-complete and is polynomial in the capacity of the backpack. This is not a contradiction to the NP-completeness of the Knapsack problem because there are many instances where the capacity is O(2^n).

Answer (score 1):

(a) Since values are integers and weights are real we make a table based on the values. To be more precise, lets fix an arbitrary order of items [image: $i_1, \dots, i_n$]. Define **DP(i, v)** be the smallest weight among subsets of items from **1** to **i** where value of each subset is at least **v**. The value of a subset is defined simply as sum of all items in that subset. Then [image: $DP(i+1, v)=min(DP(i, v - v_{i+1}) + w_{i+1}, DP(i, v))$].

**DP(i, v)** can be computed for all [image: $i=1, \dots, n$] and [image: $v=1, \dots, V^*$], the optimum value of the problem which is bounded by [image: $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i$]. After we fill up the table, i.e. computing **DP(v,i)**'s we can scan and look for the entry with maximum **v** such that **DP(i, v)** is less than or equal to **W**, i.e. the capacity of the bag.

(b) Running time is [image: $O(nV^*)$] which upper bounded by [image: $O(n \sum_{i=1}^n v_i)$]

(c) It won't contradict with the fact that Knapsack is NP-hard because the above algorithm and algorithm that you describe in the question are pseudo polynomial, i.e. they depend on the magnitude of **v<sub>i</sub>** or **w<sub>i</sub>** not their logs which are their actual size represented in computer memory!

Comment: Note that math/tex stuff doesn't work on this site. You'll have to use an API or something to get around this.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer in a nice format.